# Fresco SimpleDraweeView load local Picture won't support ResizeOptions?

Tags: image, local, fresco

```
ImageRequest request = ImageRequestBuilder.newBuilderWithSource(pictureInfo.getPictureUri())
                    .setResizeOptions(new ResizeOptions(100, 100))
                    .build();
            DraweeController controller = Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder()
                    .setOldController(pictureView.getController())
                    .setImageRequest(request)
                    .setControllerListener(new BaseControllerListener<ImageInfo>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFinalImageSet(String id, ImageInfo imageInfo, Animatable animatable) {
                            super.onFinalImageSet(id, imageInfo, animatable);
                            System.out.println("onFinalImageSet = " + imageInfo.getWidth() + " " + imageInfo.getHeight());
                        }
                    })
                    .build();
            pictureView.setController(controller);
```

When I use the code to load local picture, the imageInfo's width and height always be the original size.

The fresco have three type to resize: Scaling, Resizing and Downsampling.

If I set the resize type to Downsampling, The picture resize work well:

```
ImagePipelineConfig config = ImagePipelineConfig.newBuilder(this)
                .setDownsampleEnabled(true)
                .build();
        Fresco.initialize(this, config);
```

But when I annotate that, the picture resize work failure, then cause OutOfMemory error?

Is it my fault? Or It it a Bug?

```
compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.14.1'
```

Comment: How big are the images? What file type (JPG, PNG, ...)?

Comment: just 1920x1080,but it was a list.type is jpg and png

Comment: That's actually quite big if you want to resize it to 100x100. Ideally, you would server smaller images to the client. I suppose the problem is that there are too many images to be decoded (e.g. in a list / grid setup), which leads to the OOM